# Beta family in gam model fitting values greater than 1 and less than 0. Whats going on? (mgcv)

Tags: r, beta-distribution, gam, mgcv

I am fitting gam's to data on the interval (0,1) using the `gam` function of the `mgcv` package in R. My model code looks like this:

```
mod <- gam(y ~ x1 + x2 + s(latitude, longitude), faimly=betar(link='logit'), data = data)
```

Model fits well, but when I plot the fitted vs. observed values, it looks like this:

```
plot(data$y ~ fitted(mod), ylab='observed',xlab='fitted')
```

[image]

Clearly, the model is fitting values greater than 1 and less than 0. This is not supposed to happen. It violates the assumptions of the beta distribution. It doesn't happen when I model the same data in the `betareg` package for R. What might be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: How are you determining "fitted"? If you're using `predict`, you'll want to use the argument `type="response"`, otherwise it will go outside of the range. If you're using the `fitted` function, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Wayne I'm obtaining fitted values using `fitted(mod)`. Plotting is done with `plot(y ~ fitted(mod))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mod <- gam(y ~ x1 + x2 + s(latitude, longitude), faimly=betar(link='logit'), data = data)`

It appears if you use `faimly` (typo), `gam` doesn't complain and goes ahead and does a Gaussian. Try:

`print (mod)`

And see if it says "Family: Beta regression" or "Family: Gaussian"

Comment: woof, thanks. this was it. Would have been nice if it had thrown a warning!